# How to remove freeze UI when execute handler.postDelayed in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to show a toast after every 10 seconds, so I can use `handler.postDelayed` thread to solve this. But this thread freeze UI for 1-2 seconds, so how can I remove the freeze UI?

This is my code:

```java
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        gps = new TrackGPS(this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            mTextView.setText(address + "\n" + "Lat:" + latitude + "Lon:" + longit‌​ude);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

Comment: i see only one thread. Maybe something else is freezing the UI

Comment: But this thread repeat every 10 seconds by handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);

Comment: i understand what you're saying but be careful that it's not the proper definition of *thread*. And, the code you provided doesn't compile, so please provide the code you are actually using

Comment: `Runnable runnable= new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){    
gps=new TrackGPS(this);
if(gps1.canGetLocation()){
longitude=gps.getLongitude();
latitude=gps.getLatitude();
Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1);
String address=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);                         
mTextView.setText(address+"\n"+"Lat:"+latitude+"Lon:"+longitude);                                                       
}
handler.postDelayed(this,10000);
}
};`

Comment: consider updating your question with the code. The `handler` declaration is also important. And it would help providing all symbols you defined, for example i need to know what `TrackGPS` class is and what is the type of `gps1`

Comment: TrackGPS is a service to find current longitude and latitude. & gps1.canGetLocation() is function which returns latitude and longitude. & I will call this by runnable.run();

Comment: their description isn't enough to find the reason of UI freezing

Comment: I need to update textview with langitude and longitude every 10 seconds, so i will use this. But this can freeze UI when execute.

Comment: There are any alternative for updating textview in background without freezing UI.

Comment: actually i located the problem, i'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `Activity` class that shows where you should declare and initialize some fields, as well as how to run geocoder in a background thread with `AsyncTask`. The code doesn't compile as is because the original code snippet is missing some types and declarations.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler;

    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize other stuff

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LocationAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        };

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);
    }

    private class LocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            gps = new TrackGPS(this);
            if (gps1.canGetLocation()) {
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String[] strings = new String[3];
                strings[0] = address;
                strings[1] = latitude;
                strings[2] = longitude;
                return strings;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
            super.onPostExecute(strings);
            if (strings != null) {
                updateText(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @nandsite Thanks It's work amazing.

If I can execute functions where I use `mTextView.setText(address+"\n"+"Lat:"+latitude+"Lon:"+longitude);` with `updateText(address,latitude,longitude);` then how can i acheived this.

Comment: @ShivamKumar i didn't understand your comment, and what is `updateText()`? a method you defined?

Comment: & function body is `updateText(address,latitude,longitude){
mTextView.setText(address+"\n"+"Lat:"+latitude+"Lon:"+longitude); 
}`

Comment: @ShivamKumar you can use this method instead of `mTextView.setText()` no problem

Comment: But how can I differenciate with address,latitude and longitude. Because we got return value in s(string).

Comment: @ShivamKumar what type is latitude and longitude?

Comment: We got a result in string type varible s so how can I differenciate with address, longitude,and latitude because I use function and pass three parameters.

Comment: Longitude and Latitude is string type

Comment: @ShivamKumar please refer to the updated answer. If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it

Comment: @nandsite I accepted this answer it's working fine, But my issue is that i will use a function and pass three parameters and we received a single varivble value so how can I convert into three varibles, because I use `updateText(address,latitude,longitude){ mTextView.setText(address+"\n"+"Lat:"+latitude+"Lon:"+longit‌​ude); }` in post Execute method

Comment: @ShivamKumar and my answer hasn't been accepted yet

Comment: `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            updateText(address,latitude,longitude);
          //  mTextView.setText(s);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);
        }` and function is `updateText(address,latitude,longitude){ mTextView.setText(address+"\n"+"Lat:"+latitude+"Lon:"+longit‌​ude); }`

Comment: My question is that how to convert `mTextView.setText(s);` into `updateText(address,latitude,longitude);`

Comment: Thank you so much @nandsite I acheived this by split. Thanks a lot. This is help me.

Comment: @ShivamKumar if you feel like it, please accept my answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers